# Remove whitespace before *

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, ch

i'm trying to write a function that changes HTML-code to a new markup-languange. Where **br** and **/br** is replaced by *. Although, after the first * (**br**) no whitespace is allowed and before the second * (**/br**) no whitespace is allowed. An example is given bellow.

Strong emphasis

• The start and end of a section with strong emphasis is defined by '*'.

• The starting * must not be followed by Whitespace. The ending * must not be preceded by
Whitespace. As an example, * fat cat*, *fat cat * and * fat cat * are not permitted

Comment: Your code trying to do it can be found in? and the problem with it is?

Comment: Could you please provide an exact example of input HTML, expected output string, the actual output you are receiving, and the code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda vague on what you're using. If you're Using VB then this might help

Get the substring inside `br` by removing the `br` tag first then trim the trailing whitespaces on that substring using `.Trim`. Finally add the `*` on bothsides

```
Dim Oldstring As String = "br fat cat /br"
Dim Newstring As String = "*" + Oldstring.Substring(2, Oldstring.Length - 5).Trim + "*"
```